# How to check if a tag is wrapped in CDATA tag?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, cdata

I have the following xml:

```
<tag-name lang="en_GB"><![CDATA[Contents 123]]></tag-name>
<tag-name lang="en_US"><![CDATA[Contents 456]]></tag-name>
```

Which I've read into Beautifulsoup like this:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
```

However, when I print out the soup (completely or using soup.find('tag-name'), I get the following result:

```
<tag-name lang="en_GB">Contents 123</tag-name>
<tag-name lang="en_US">Contents 456</tag-name>
```

As you can see the CDATA wrapper has gone. My question now is, is it possible to or:

- not delete the CDATA tags in the Soup?
- find out if a tag is wrapped in a CDATA tag (so I can manually add it back)?

My end goal is to change the string values ('Contents 123' and 'Contents 456') and returning that XML to the user, without changing the rest of the XML (like removing CDATA tags).

Comment: Have to look at `xmltodict` https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict

Comment: Try using `html.parser` instead of `xml`